# How to choose prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Which is right:

> 1.The dog is friendly ***to/with*** me.
>    2.My classmate is friendly ***to/with*** me.

How would I choose the right one.

Comment: You can be friends **of** someone, friends/friendly **with** someone or (feel) friendly **towards** someone.

Comment: Looks like it depends on if the preceding words are nouns or adjectives or adverbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start off by saying that you can be friends **with** someone, you can be friendly **to** someone, you can be **a** friend **of** someone, or you can be friendly **towards** someone. These all mean almost the same thing, which I'll get into.

"I'm friends **with** X" and "I'm **a** friend **of** X" both mean the same thing, that X is your friend and the relationship is mutual.

"I'm friendly **with** X" is similar in meaning, but more ambiguous, and doesn't imply as close of a relationship. You wouldn't say this about your best friends, you would say this about your coworker that you'd go out for some beers with after work in a group but probably not alone. You two aren't super close, but you have a positive relationship and really don't hate each other - you're friendly with each other.

Now, be careful using this term. to "**get friendly with** X" has a mild sexual connotation; it can mean flirting or more. If you told your friend to go "**get friendly with**" a girl at a bar, you're telling him to try and take her home. If some girls "**got friendly with**" the football team, it implies that they had sex.

The terms "being friendly **towards** X" and "being friendly **to** X" are usually equivalent. The relationship implied is even more ambiguous - we don't know whether or not the friendliness is reciprocated, just that someone's being nice to someone.

Again, there is a sexual connotation under the surface - if someone is "**too** friendly", that's a polite way too call them creepy or overly sexual. If someone's flirting too much with someone's wife, the husband would say that they were "**too friendly**" to his wife. If someone's being mildly creepy, "**too friendly**" can be used as well. Additionally, if I saw some guy making out with his girlfriend in public, I would say that they were "**getting too friendly**".

I hope this helps :D

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it for people. What about dogs? - I think only "with" is right then, isn't it?